# how to convert a string into numeric values in R

Tags: r

I have a string like "[0 0.1 0.2 0.4]" and what I want is to strip parentheses and retrieve values as numeric. I am able to strip parentheses, but when it comes to convert to numeric, then I have an error with NA:

```
cleanList <- function(aString){
   temp <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", aString)
   as.numeric(temp)
}
```

is there a way to convert each of the character in the string into numbers?

EDIT: here's another approach that uses stringr:

```
cleanList <- function(aString){
   as.numeric(str_extract_all(aString,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")[[1]])
}
cleanList("[0 0.1 0.2 0.4]")
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split `temp` into a vector and then call `as.numeric` on that. Assuming the numbers in `temp` are separated by spaces,

```
temp2 <- unlist(strsplit(temp, " "))
as.numeric(temp2)
# 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.4
```

Alternatively, `do.call(as.numeric, strsplit(temp, " "))` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit`:

```
as.numeric( strsplit( temp, " " )[[1]] )
```

See the documentation on `?strsplit` for details.